# Visual Studio 2017 - No Events in Events Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Not a single event is showing in the Events window, no Program output, Thread output, no Expections Catched/Thrown nothing at all.

Im using Visual Studio Community 2017 (maybe why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a feature for Professional Up. Doesn't seem to be working for Community but the moment I installed Enterprise it worked perfectly.